# jQuery mobile not going through ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am making an audio app.
When I click over the Play button, then its id should be changed dynamically - like id = "paused".
Then by clicking over that, it should pause, but which is not working.

```
$('#pauses').click(function())
```

When I click the pause button, it still plays.

Please take look over example: https://jsfiddle.net/shivam_sh/4zL4en10/2/

Comment: please don't link on any website with code, since the content of the website can change and the answers posted on stackoverflow consequently might be wrong

Comment: Changing a DOM element's id dynamically is unusual to say the least.

Comment: Yes that will be not be a good thing to do, try class or you can also go for the simple change that i just mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make simple changes to make it work. Change your html add `data-status`

```
<a data-role="button" data-status="play" data-theme="a" id="play" href="#">Play</a>
```

And for JavaScript code you can do this.

```
$('#play').click(function() {
  if($(this).data('status') == "play") {
    $(this).text("P A U S E");
    $(this).data('status', 'pause');
    doPlay();
  } else {
    $(this).text("P L A Y"); 
    $(this).data('status', 'play');
    doPause();
  }  
});
```

[jsfiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/4zL4en10/6/)

P.s: Avoid making amendments to `id` of `elements`

Comment: let me know if works for you and accept the answer so it can help someone else as well.